# How can I record the score to a file and recall it with Python

Tags: python

I'm doing a mini project for a short course and I've done all the required bits as well as some of the optional tasks. For something a little extra I wanted to work out how to write the score to a file and be able to recall it later. I'm just not sure how I would go about this.

Below is what i've got so far any help to understand it would be great!

```
import random
from typing import Any

import requests

my_score = 0
opponent_score = 0

print("~~ Welcome to the Pokemon Top Trumps Game! ~~ \n")
player1name = input("Player 1, please enter your name: ")
print("Hello " + player1name + ", get ready to enter the world of Pokemon!\n")

choice = True
while choice:


    def random_pokemon():
        pokemon_number = random.randint(1, 151)
        url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{}/'.format(pokemon_number)
        response = requests.get(url)
        pokemon = response.json()
        global my_score
        global opponent_score

        return {
            'name': pokemon['name'],
            'id': pokemon['id'],
            'height': pokemon['height'],
            'weight': pokemon['weight'],
            'hp': pokemon['stats'][0]['base_stat'],
            'attack': pokemon['stats'][1]['base_stat'],
            'defense': pokemon['stats'][2]['base_stat'],
            'special-attack': pokemon['stats'][3]['base_stat'],
            'special-defense': pokemon['stats'][4]['base_stat'],
            'speed': pokemon['stats'][5]['base_stat'],
        }


    my_pokemon = random_pokemon()
    print('You were given {}'.format(my_pokemon['name']))
    stat_choice = input(
    'Which stat do you want to use? (id, height, weight, hp, attack, defense, special-attack, special-defense, speed) ')

    opponent_pokemon = random_pokemon()
    print('The opponent got {}'.format(opponent_pokemon['name']))

    my_stat = my_pokemon[stat_choice]
    opponent_stat = opponent_pokemon[stat_choice]

    if my_stat > opponent_stat:
        print('Your value is')
        print(my_stat)
        print('Your opponents value is')
        print(opponent_stat)
        print('You Win!')
        my_score = my_score +1
        print("Your points: " + str(my_score))

    elif my_stat < opponent_stat:
        print('Your value is')
        print(my_stat)
        print('Your opponents value is')
        print(opponent_stat)
        print('You Lose!')
        opponent_score = opponent_score + 1
        print("Opponent points: " + str(opponent_score))

    else:
        print('Draw!')

    play_again = input('Play again? (Y/N): ')
    
    if play_again.upper() != 'Y':
        choice = False
```

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files already?

Comment: Hiya yeh i had read that but it's not making sense to me how to do it for my code

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what @mkrieger1 has suggested about using internal Python [Read and Write](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) functions.

I would suggest use [Pandas](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/default.asp) library and export the data into csv like format

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'Your Stat': my_stat, 
'Your Score' : my_score,
'Opponent Stat': opponent_stat,
'Opponent Score': opponent_score
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('score.csv')
```